# Число вхождений подстроки в строку через цикл и IndexOf без учета регистра символов

Tags: c#, строки

Всем Привет!

сделал программу с функцией которая должна делать следующее, прочитать текст из файла, и функция, которая считает количество вхождений некоторой строки в этот текст без учета регистра символов, нужно сделать  с использование цикл и IndexOf , который принимает начальный индекс, с которого искать?

Код не работает выдаёт нули, подскажите пожалуйста что поправить?

```
   public static int GetAmountOccurrences(string inputString, string searchString)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;

        while (!true)
        {
            if (inputString.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string currentLine;
        string[] splits = new string[2];
        int i = 0;
        string searchString = "r";

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("..\\..\\input.txt"))
        {
            while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                splits[i] = currentLine;
                Console.WriteLine("Количество вхождений строки {0} = {1} ", splits[i], GetAmountOccurrences(splits[i], searchString));
                i++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Чтение выполнено");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: вас не смущает это `while (!true)`? Потому и не работает - цикл ни разу не выполнится. Исправляйте условие, только не на `while (true)`, если не хотите получить "вечный" цикл. Какое именно должно быть условие - придется немного подумать самостоятельно, иначе ничему не научитесь

Comment: Ну и IndexOf() возвращает первое вхождение, так что, какой-то странный count у вас. UPD: Там вторым аргументом можно задавать смещение, но у вас все равно это не реализовано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int GetAmountOccurrences(string inputString, string searchString)
{
    int i = 0;
    int x = -1;
    int count = -1; 
    while (i != -1)
    {
        i = inputString.IndexOf(searchString, x + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
        x = i;
        count++; 
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! у меня почему то не работает? i нужная переменная?
x + 1 можно ли после нахождения вхождения можно сдвинуться дальше, чем на 1 ?

Comment: а, дык у вас зачем-то массив используется `string[] splits = new string[2];`, вместо `splits[i]` используйте `currentLine`, а если хотите сохранять в массив строку, то юзайте `List<string>` и `Add` `var list = new List<string>(); list.Add(currentLine);` не знаю правда зачем вам это

Comment: перменная `i` это значение которое вернет `indexOf`, если подстрока не найдена `indexOf` вернет -1, сохраняете найденный индекс в `x` и дальше ищите в этой же строке следующее вхождение от предыдущего индекса x + 1

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
public static int GetAmountOccurrences(string inputString, string searchString)
    {
        return Regex.Matches(inputString, searchString).Count;
    }
```

Comment: а как же регистр?)

Comment: Ну чувак писал, что регистр не нужен)

Comment: ну вроде как его слова (да и в коде так) значат "вне зависимости от регистра")

Comment: Точно, ты прав. Он это просто как-то хитро написал.